# Multi-threaded sort

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, sorting

I wanted to write a multi-threaded sort, but unfortunately I don't know much about threads, especially in C++11. I managed to make something work, but I would be highly surprised if it was the best way to do it.

```
template<class T>
void ___sort(T *data, int len, int nbThreads){
    if(nbThreads<2){
        std::sort(data, (&(data[len])), std::less<T>());
    }
    else{

        std::future<void> b = std::async(std::launch::async,___sort<T>, data, len/2, nbThreads-2);
        std::future<void> a = std::async(std::launch::async,___sort<T>, &data[len/2], len/2, nbThreads-2);

        a.wait();
        b.wait();

        std::inplace_merge (data,&data[len/2],&data[len],std::less<T>());
    }
}
```

Some of the tests I did sorting integers:

`size` is the number of `int`s sorted, and the time is in seconds.

> ```
> size : 2097152
> time with 1 thread : 4.961
> time with 2 thread : 3.191
> time with 4 thread : 2.377
>
> size : 4194304
> time with 1 thread : 10.002
> time with 2 thread : 6.214
> time with 4 thread : 4.689
>
> size : 8388608
> time with 1 thread : 19.975
> time with 2 thread : 12.332
> time with 4 thread : 9.29
>
> size : 16777216
> time with 1 thread : 38.712
> time with 2 thread : 25.257
> time with 4 thread : 18.706
> ```

Also, I tried using `std::qsort` instead of `std::sort`, and the results were at least twice as long as that.  Any reasons why?

Comment: Don't use '__' in an identifer name.http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/14065

Comment: I think that one additional optimisation could be to avoid "false sharing" of cache line between threads.
The way the buffer is divided this could happen with the current code..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this is probably more efficient:

```
template<class T>
void parallel_sort(T* data, int len, int grainsize)
{
    // Use grainsize instead of thread count so that we don't e.g.
    // spawn 4 threads just to sort 8 elements.
    if(len < grainsize)
    {
        std::sort(data, data + len, std::less<T>());
    }
    else
    {
        auto future = std::async(parallel_sort<T>, data, len/2, grainsize);

        // No need to spawn another thread just to block the calling 
        // thread which would do nothing.
        parallel_sort(data + len/2, len - len/2, grainsize);

        future.wait();

        std::inplace_merge(data, data + len/2, data + len, std::less<T>());
    }
}
```

You could set grain size to something like, `std::max(256, len/nb_threads)`.

Comment: Yes I don't want 4 threads to sort 8 items. But then again I don't want to spawn more threads than I have parallelism available (not more ((1.0 -> 1.5) * <available cores>)). So I would use a combination of these two techniques.

Comment: @LokiAstari: See my suggestion below the code, set grainsize to e.g. `std::max(256, len/nb_threads)`:

Comment: parallel_sort(data + len/2, len/2, grainsize); should be: parallel_sort(data + len/2, len - len/2, grainsize);